# dealloc UIImagePickerController error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view which contains a button image picker. When I close the view I am also deallocating the UIImagePickerController.

```
@interface XXPictureCell()<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;
@end

@implementation XXPictureCell
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.imagePickerController.delegate = nil;
}

//...

- (UIImagePickerController *)imagePickerController
{
    if (!_imagePickerController)
    {
        _imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        _imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        _imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
        _imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        _imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    }
    return _imagePickerController;
}
@end
```

The error I keep receiving is

```
Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x7fa9e18dc600) of class XXPictureCell. It is possible that this object was over-released, or is in the process of deallocation.
```

Comment: Setting the delegate to `nil` in `dealloc` is unnecessary.  Remove the `dealloc` method entirely and see if the error resolves.  If not you'll need to post more code.

Comment: It appears you got this out of these codes.

Comment: That indeed fixed my problem, @par. Thanks. If you answer I will ✓ you.

Comment: Yes, agree no need to set nil in dealloc. BTW, one more best practice is not to use accessor in dealloc: http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-init/